# Веб-приложение Как это связать и писать?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Совершенно запутался с тем, как это писать.
Нужно написать именно свое приложение. Оно должно подключаться к сайту отеля, к примеру.
Специализировано оно для владельца этого малого отеля. Он логинится, далее в этом приложении будет отображаться карта кликов, айпи, истории действий пользователей, сколько их было и тд. Данные получать эти с сайта в БД и отражать в приложении, возможно с добавлением графиков.
Я понимаю, что есть метрики, но это нужно написать самостоятельно, своё. В реальном времени или с задержкой - не знаю.

Стек: JavaScript, Node.JS, React, MySQL
Примерно такой, но может и дополнится/убавится что-то.

Не могли дать ссылок, может направить в какое-то нужное русло, чтобы создать такое. Запутался: как будет подключаться это приложение к чужому сайту, чтобы собирать данные с него / как это всё будет взаимосвязано и т.д.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Есть гугл, вы можете найти все необходимые ссылки там. Как делать запросы fetch, axios. Если у вас нет api то вам нужно самому написать бэк. И тд. Это много информации. Начните с простого, что такое js